# change the color of label in UICollectionView iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview

hi I am working on with collection view for a calendar. I put a label in the collection view. I give the value to this label from a static array in which I add the months name. Now I have to change the color of label according to the value 0 and 1. if 1 then label turn into green and if 0 then red. These 0 and 1 values I got form the JSON. I put these values in the array.

Now my problem when I use this array in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` then its crash because the count of rows is 12 and the count of valueArray is 2. Is there any way to work with this. thanks..!

Comment: Why is the count of valueArray 2?

Comment: I have two arrays. In first array there is name of months and in the other array there is 0 and 1 value. so i create the rows according to the count of month array. Now i have to change the color of label according to the 0 and 1 value. But my value array's count is 2 or less than the month array.  i want to know any way to resolve this. OR any other way to do this task.. Thanks

Comment: U want to apply the red if 0 and green if 1...to all the rows or one single row..?I mean ValueArray is the array coming from webservice or u r saving in any object..?

Comment: can you give your valueArray? is it contain json or direct 0,1 on indexs?

Comment: guys in JSON i have a parameter which value is 0 or 1. I put the value of that parameter in value array. and then i want to use this array in collection view's cellForItemAtIndexPath so that its label can change the color according to the valuearray's value.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inconsistency in your data model.

1) Wherever your data is coming from (network, JSON..etc.) you need to end up with NSDictionary of key value pairs.
Key - month
Value - red or blue

2) Then in collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection: you should return number of items in dictionary like this

```
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
    return [dictionary allKeys] count];
}
```

3) In your ViewController create a month mapping array. Simple NSArray that will contain 12 NSStrings - your months.

```
-(NSArray *)months
{
return @[@"january",
         @"february",
         @"march"
         @"april",
         @"may",
         @"june"
         @"july",
         @"august",
         @"september",
         @"october",
         @"november",
         @"december"];
```

}

4) Finally you will handle your concrete item in didSelectItem... by retrieving a month for a particular index..and then setting the cell to match the value for that month...and based on value you will set the color.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didDeselectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //....other code here

    NSString *month = self.monthsArray[indexpath.row];
    NSString *value = self.monthsDictionary[month];

    if (value isEqualToString:@"red")
    { 
        coolectionViewCell.color = [UIColor redColor];
    }
   etc..
```

BONUS:
You did not say what red and green means, but you really should declare an enumeration for that thing as this is a custom type. You would wrap your enums in the dictionary as NSNumbers.
Also the month mapping array is kind of rudimentary but I did not want to overwhelm you. I am sure NSDateFormatter has some kind of mechanism to play with months in a comprehensive localised way.

Comment: i want to use it in the cellForItemAtIndexPath method of collection view. Pls help me out if any way to resolve this